# Site Navigation @ StackOverflow.com

Tags: discussion, navigation

I think it is <del>difficult</del> not perfectly smooth to navigate the StackOverflow.com site. Next to the logo, there are a number of major categories: Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, and Unanswered. And in every category, there are a number of subcategories, displayed as tabs (e.g. newest, featured, hot, votes, and active under major category Questions).

- Shouldn't the major category Unanswered rather be a subcategory of Questions?

If you ask me, "unanswered questions" should be treated as "hot questions" and "questions with many up-votes /and few down-votes/". Also, if you click a tag on the main page (which belongs to no major category at all), you end up at [a tag main page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi). But the subcategory of this page (newest, active, ...) depends on the last tab clicked, and hence is not part of the URL. This is slightly confusing. To make it worse

- On this tag main page, there is a *third* toolbar of links (about the ... tag, faq, stats, hot answers, ...), but the links are confusing.

If you click e.g. "new answers", you end up in the Tags main category, and thus you leave the Questions main category by clicking link on a "third-order" navigation toolbar.

Also, it is not entirely self-evident that https://stackoverflow.com/tags/delphi/new is a list of all new answers tagged Delphi, whereas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi is (if you select the right tab!) a list of all new questions tagged Delphi.

Finally, what is the difference between https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured under no main category, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured under the Questions main category?

It might be usable enough, but the navigation feels rather unstructured.

Comment: I'm not sure difficult is the right word, but there are some unintuitive aspects.

Comment: @Fosco: You are right. It is not difficult at all. I mean that the structure of the site is not perfectly (to say the least) clear.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your point about tabs being remembered. I don't like the behavior that if I go to the "Featured" tab, that next time I visit the site I will still be there. I don't think, that this is expected behavior. I always want to get back to the "Newest" tab and visit the other tabs only for looking at them *once*.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there is now a tab for unanswered on the question views, e.g. when you are viewing questions by tag or browsing the complete list of questions.